# I have used jsp and java beans for an application of music store.but the set and get methods are not working

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

here is my jsp page

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@ page import="Mybean.Bean"%>

<html>
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <title>Music Store</title>
   </head>
   <jsp:useBean id="bn" scope="page" class="Mybean.Bean" type="Bean"/>
       <jsp:setProperty name="bn" property="searchbox"  />
   <body style="text-align:center" bgcolor="teal">
       <h1>Welcome to Music Store</h1>
       <hr align="center" size="3" style="background-color:silver" width="80%">
       <br>
       <form action="index.jsp" method="post">
           <A HREF="Albums.jsp">All Albums</A>
           <font face="Verdana" size="3" style="font-weight:bold">Search</font>&nbsp;
           <select id="ddList" name="ddList">
               <option id="op1" value="Album">Album</option>
               <option id="op2" value="Song">Song</option>
               <option id="op3" value="Artist">Artist</option>
           </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <input type="text"  name="searchBox" size="50" value="">&nbsp;
           <input type="submit" value="Go"><br><br>
       </form>
       <div name="asshole"></div>
       <div align="center" style="background-color:teal;">
           <h3>Search Result</h3>
           <table style="border:blue;" bgcolor="silver" border="3" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

<%

if(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("post")){
    //out.println("yeah am here");
     try {
           Connection cn = null;
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           String serverName = "localhost";
           String mydatabase = "musicstore";
           String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + mydatabase; // a JDBC url
           String username = "root";
           String password = "root";
           String albumnme="",songnme="",artistnme="";
           String searchType = request.getParameter("ddList");
           //out.println("search type: "+searchType);

           cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        try {
           java.sql.Statement stmt = cn.createStatement();
           java.sql.Statement stmt1 = cn.createStatement();
           java.sql.Statement stmt2 = cn.createStatement();
           ResultSet rs = null;

           if(searchType.equals("Album")){
%>
               <tr bgcolor="#662835"><td width="150">Song</td><td width="150">Artist</td></tr>
<%

                rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT songsinfo.songtitle,artistinfo.artistName FROM albuminfo,songsinfo,artistinfo where albuminfo.albumtitle = '"+bn.getSearchbox()+"' AND  songsinfo.albumID = albuminfo.albumID AND songsinfo.songid = artistinfo.songID");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    if(!rs.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase(songnme)){
%>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%out.println(rs.getString(1));%></td>
                            <td><%out.println(rs.getString(2));%>
<%
                    }
                    else if(!rs.getString(2).equalsIgnoreCase(artistnme)){
%>
                        ,<%out.println(rs.getString(2));%>
<%  
                    }
                    else{
%>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
<%                         

                    }
                    songnme = rs.getString(1);
                    artistnme = rs.getString(2);
               }
           }
           else if(searchType.equals("Song")){//out.println("hey2");
               %>
               <tr bgcolor="#662835"><%--<td width="150">Song</td>--%><td width="150">Album</td><td width="150">Artist</td></tr>
               <jsp:getProperty name="bn" property="searchbox" />
               <%

                rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT songsinfo.songid,artistinfo.artistName,albuminfo.albumtitle FROM songsinfo,artistinfo,albuminfo WHERE songsinfo.songtitle ='"+bn.getSearchbox()+"' AND songsinfo.songid =artistinfo.songId AND songsinfo.albumid = albuminfo.albumID;");
               while (rs.next()) {
                   //artistnme = artistnme + rs.getString(2) + ",";
                   //albmnme = rs.getString(3);
                        if(!rs.getString(3).equalsIgnoreCase(albumnme)){
                   %>
                    <tr>
                    <%--<td><%out.println(rs.getString(1));%></td>--%>
                    <td><%out.println(rs.getString(3));%></td>
                    <td><%out.println(rs.getString(2));%>
<%
                    }
                    else if(!rs.getString(2).equalsIgnoreCase(artistnme)){
%>
                        ,<%out.println(rs.getString(2));%>
<%
                    }
                    else{
%>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
<%

                    }
                    albumnme = rs.getString(3);
                    artistnme = rs.getString(2);
               }
                   //out.println("album name ="+albmnme);
                   //out.println("song name ="+searchText);
                   //out.println("artist name ="+artistnme);
          }
           else if(searchType.equals("Artist")){//out.println("hey3");
               %>
               <tr bgcolor="#662835"><td width="150">Album</td><td width="150">Song</td></tr>
               <%
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT albuminfo.albumtitle,songsinfo.songtitle,artistinfo.artistName FROM albuminfo,songsinfo,artistinfo where artistinfo.artistName ='"+bn.getSearchbox()+"' AND songsinfo.songid = artistinfo.songId AND albuminfo.albumid = artistinfo.albumID");
                    while (rs.next()) {
                   //albmnme = rs.getString(1);
                   //songnme = songnme + rs.getString(2) +",";
                   //artistnme = artistnme + rs.getString(3) + ",";
                        if(!rs.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase(albumnme)){
               %>
                            <tr>
                            <td><%out.println(rs.getString(1));%></td>
                            <td><%out.println(rs.getString(2));%><%
                            }
                        else if(!rs.getString(2).equalsIgnoreCase(songnme)){
%>
                            <%out.println(rs.getString(2));%>
<%
                        }
                        else{
%>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
<%
                        }
                    albumnme = rs.getString(1);
                    songnme = rs.getString(2);
               }

                   //out.println("album name ="+searchText);
                   //out.println("song name ="+songnme);
                   //out.println("artist name ="+artistnme);
          }
           //ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM albuminfo where albumtitle='"+searchText+"'");


               stmt.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("sorry no data found");
       }

       } catch (Exception e) {
           out.println(e);
       }
}
%>
       </table>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

heres my bean class

```
package Mybean;
public class Bean
{
  private String searchbox;


    public String getSearchbox() {
        return searchbox;
    }

    public void setSearchbox(String searchbox) {
        System.out.println("inside set");
        this.searchbox = searchbox;
    }


}
```

Comment: Educate yourself on topics like "SQL injection" and "Cross-Site Scripting". It's worth it when you build publicly accessible web applications.

Comment: What means Roland Illing is that you should use PreparedStatment instead of using construction of request string by hand

Comment: The code is indeed terrible, but a music store is a typical homework/selfpractice application. Those security lessons and proper resource handling (this code will crash after running a couple of hours intensively) and clean code separation (it lacks controller, domain and DAO classes) shall (hopefully) come later if s/he is following a *decent* education or book. @Xavier: `PreparedStatement` only prevents SQL injection attacks, not XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that you did not use the same case sensitivity you should use

```
<jsp:getProperty name="bn" property="searchBox" />
```

instead of

```
<jsp:getProperty name="bn" property="searchbox" />
```